# App crash with Lenovo Yoga tab 3 but not with emulator

Tags: java, android

Im running genymotion and when i test the app on the emulator its fine, but as soon as i try runing it on a lenovo yoga tab 3 it crahes. 
This is the logcat

08-24 09:54:33.192 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-24 09:54:34.210 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 223(22KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 57% free, 743KB/1767KB, paused 471us total 11.763ms
08-24 09:54:34.238 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 58% free, 731KB/1755KB, paused 682us total 21.954ms
08-24 09:54:34.239 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 99MB allocation
08-24 09:54:34.258 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 58% free, 730KB/1754KB, paused 613us total 18.430ms
08-24 09:54:34.262 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 104530188 byte allocation with 1048480 free bytes and 95MB until OOM"
08-24 09:54:34.275 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 58% free, 730KB/1754KB, paused 541us total 7.420ms
08-24 09:54:34.295 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 58% free, 730KB/1754KB, paused 591us total 18.615ms
08-24 09:54:34.296 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 99MB allocation
08-24 09:54:34.315 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 58% free, 730KB/1754KB, paused 459us total 18.624ms
08-24 09:54:34.316 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 104530188 byte allocation with 1048480 free bytes and 95MB until OOM"
08-24 09:54:34.316 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
08-24 09:54:34.335 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
                                                                            --------- beginning of crash
```

08-24 09:54:34.340 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.mauricio.pairlines, PID: 16995
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mauricio.pairlines/com.example.mauricio.pairlines.PasswordVerification}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                    at com.example.mauricio.pairlines.PasswordVerification.onCreate(PasswordVerification.java:27)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                    at com.example.mauricio.pairlines.PasswordVerification.onCreate(PasswordVerification.java:27) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 104530188 byte allocation with 1048480 free bytes and 95MB until OOM
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:608)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.(View.java:3741)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:498)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:200)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:196)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:192)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                    at com.example.mauricio.pairlines.PasswordVerification.onCreate(PasswordVerification.java:27) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
08-24 09:54:34.669 16995-16995/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16995 SIG: 9

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 104530188 byte allocation` You've got a 100MB image file among your resources?

Comment: @Michael How di i check?

Comment: By going through the project on your development machine. Surely you should know (or easily be able to find out) which resources you're including in this Activity's layout.

Comment: the whole project is 90.5 MB (94,901,815 bytes) so i dont know where i should look for a  104530188 file

Comment: It might not necessarily be that size on disk. Images are often stored compressed, and then decompressed when they are displayed on the device.

Comment: @Michael only image i have is 2.81 MB (2,956,247 bytes)

Comment: @Michael so what do i do with this compressed image?

Comment: Well, by the looks of it, your layout for `PasswordVerification` includes some drawable that is very large. You could try going through the layout xml and remove elements until you find the culprit.

Comment: @Michael what i mean is that the only drawable i got is the bg , how do i keep it without crash, the only things in PasswordVerification are 2 Edit text , 1 Text view, 1 Çbutton and 1 linear layout, and the bg image

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed , i just added 4 folders on the res folder called  drawable xhdpi,drawable hdpi,drawable mdpi and drawable ldpi and moved the image there, then i rezised the image on photoshop to 72dpi on the xhdpi, 3/4 the size on hdpi, 1/2 in mdpi and 1/4 in ldpi.